# select values from listbox in selenium webdriver not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My below code is not working for the select values from list box. I want to select the value "Mouse" from the list.

Page factory code

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//select")
private WebElement lstDevice;
public WebElement lstSelectDevice() {
lstDevice.click();
new Select(lstSelectDevice()).selectByVisibleText("Mouse");
return lstDevice;
```

}

Page steps code

```
lstSelectDevice().click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the code where `Select` is initialized. The constructor of `Select` needs a `WebElement` to be passed to it. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//select")
private WebElement lstDevice;

public WebElement lstSelectDevice() {

    new Select(lstDevice).selectByVisibleText("Mouse");
    return lstDevice; //Not sure why u need this...
}
```